# Why is my simple JSON retrieval code not working with OMDb?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have been completely stumped trying to figure this out, it's 2 simple files, one .html and one .js file the code looks like it should be able to send the user input aka searchvalue to the url string and retrieve info, but for some reason it is not working. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> test </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<main>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search for movies by title..." id="input">
  <button id="button">Submit</button>

  <div id="jsonresults">

  </div>
</main>
</html>
```

```
function display() {
    var searchValue = $("#input").val();
  var data = "&&t="+searchValue
    var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=c06f36b1"

    $.get(url,data).done(function(response){
        $("#jsonresults").append("<p>" + response.length + " movies with the searched title</p>");
        for (var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
            $("#jsonresults").append("<h3>"+response[i].Title+" <br><img src="+response[i].Poster+" style='width:50px;'></h3>")
            .append("<p>Year of Release: "+response[i].Year+"</p>")
      .append("<p>IMDB Rating: "+response[i].Value+"</p>")
        }

    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR){
        alert("Error" + jqXHR.status)
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").on("click",display);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the api guide for omdb for search you should be using `s` as query string parameter.

Also your logic to display the output file does not matches the omdb output format. You can check the output format by querying the api in the browser it self.

[http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[api_key]&s=snowden](http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=%5Bapi_key%5D&s=snowden)

So to fix your problem change &t to &s on query string and change the logic on the loop to use `response.Search`

```js
function display() {
  var searchValue = $("#input").val();
  var data = "s=" + searchValue
  var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=c06f36b1"

  $.get(url, data).done(function(response) {
      $("#jsonresults").append("<p>" + response.Search.length + " movies with the searched title</p>");
      for (var i = 0; i < response.Search.length; i++) {
        $("#jsonresults").append("<h3>" + response.Search[i].Title + " <br><img src=" + response.Search[i].Poster + " style='width:50px;'></h3>")
          .append("<p>Year of Release: " + response.Search[i].Year + "</p>")
          .append("<p>IMDB Rating: " + response.Search[i].Value + "</p>")
      }

    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR) {
      alert("Error" + jqXHR.status)
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").on("click", display);
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> test </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<main>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search for movies by title..." id="input">
  <button id="button">Submit</button>

  <div id="jsonresults">

  </div>
</main>

</html>
```